# Gurobi python : error with indexing var in callback for lazy constraint

Tags: python-2.7, callback, constraints, gurobi

Could somebody please help me with this error:

When I use callback for add lazy constraints, I received this the follow message:

`Exception TypeError: 'Var' object does not support indexing in 'gurobipy.callbackstub' ignored`.

The error comes from the line which contains "selected". I try to test 2 versions of callback without success. I have alos try to run the example of TSP on Gurobi but model._vars.keys() dont work. I use Gurobi 6.5.2 and Python 2.7. Print model._vZ give :

```
[<gurobi.Var vZ_j((9, 6, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P2')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((9, 6, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P3')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((9, 6, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P4')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((9, 6, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P5')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((3, 8, 6), 2)_i((10, 7, 5), 3)_e(3, 'P1')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((3, 8, 6), 2)_i((10, 7, 5), 3)_e(3, 'P2')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((3, 8, 6), 2)_i((10, 7, 5), 3)_e(3, 'P3')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((3, 8, 6), 2)_i((10, 7, 5), 3)_e(3, 'P4')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((3, 8, 6), 2)_i((10, 7, 5), 3)_e(3, 'P5')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((10, 10, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P1')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((10, 10, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P2')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((10, 10, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P3')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((10, 10, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P4')>, <gurobi.Var vZ_j((10, 10, 6), 3)_i((4, 7, 6), 3)_e(3, 'P5')>]
```

[, , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Thanks

```
def subtourelim(model, where):
    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        vZs = model.cbGetSolution(model._vZ)
        vXs = model.cbGetSolution(model._vX)
        opeqp= model._OpEqP
        nz=model._nz
        for e in opeqp:
            selected = [(model._vZ[i][0],model._vZ[i][1]) for i in range(nz) if model._vZ[i][2]==e and model._vZ[i][1]!=(b1,T)]            
            bti=b0
            chaine_primo=[]            
            while True:
                bti=[bt for bt in BlocsEPT if vZs[bti,bt,e]>0.5][0]
                if bit!=(b1,T):
                    chaine_primo.append(bti)
                else:
                    break
            unvisit=[bt for bt in Blocs_EP if vXs[bt,e]>0.5 and bt not in chaine_primo]
            if len(unvisit)>0:
                tour = subtour(selected,unvisit,chaine_primo,Blocs_EP)
                ArcsTour=[(bt0,bt1) for bt in tour for bt1 in tour if (bt0,bt1) in CBloc_T and vZs[bt0,bt1,e]>0.5]
                model.cbLazy(quicksum(model._vZ[ct[0],ct[1],e] for ct in ArcsTour) <= len(tour)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i found the solution :

```
selected = tuplelist((cte[0],cte[1]) for cte in model._vZ if cte[2]==e if  model.cbGetSolution(model._vZ[cte]) > 0.5 and cte[1]!=(Fb1,FT))
```

"model._vZ" came from "model.getVars()" whitch this a list. I change it to "model._vZ = varZ" which is dictionnary and then applied evaluate "selected"